# Can I precompile Rails assets in another project or just not compile them at all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm working with a legacy Rails 3.2.8 app that doesn't have a proper development environment, deployment strategy, or code repo in place. I'm worried about compiling assets and not being able to rollback if I need to, so I'd rather not deal with compilation if I can avoid it.

My question is... can I put new assets directly into the public/assets folder and skip fingerprinting, etc? Is there another deployment piece under the hood that I'm missing and will cause me major problems afterward?

Another option I've considered is compiling the new assets in an external application, putting them into the public/assets folder and manually updating the manifest.yml file.

Comment: Adding assets in public/assets works perfectly fine - except that you lose the minification and fingerprinting features. The lack of fingerprinting can give "sticky" assets where the browser may hold on to a stale cached version.

Comment: You can setup Sprockets in a separate repo without an entire Rails stack, or use alternatives like Webpack. Instead of placing the assets in `app/assets` you can use a CDN like AWS to deploy the assets - which is also good for performance.